# Google Sheets - Send email based on cell matching True or False

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I don't work with Google Sheets very often and mainly deal with Google Form's script editor. We have created a database from various forms that fill into one spreadsheet and I would like to send email notifications to specific managers based on the recent row update, which would update from a form submission. Here is what I was trying to get it to do:

if cell in Column P matches to "FALSE":

- send email
- set the recipient field as "director1@gmail.com" if cell in Column J matches to the word "Building 1"
- set the CC field as "manager1@gmail.com" if the cell in Column I matches to the word "Department 1"

if Column P matches to "TRUE", then it doesn't have to do anything

```
function triggerOnEdit(e)
{
  alertManagers(e);
}


function checkClearance(e)
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Calculations");
  var value = sheet.getRange("P:P").getValue();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1); //understands spreadsheet
  
  if(range.getColumn() <= 16 && 
     range.getLastColumn() >=16 )
  {
    var edited_row = range.getRow();
    
    var approval = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(edited_row,16).getValue();
    if(approval == 'FALSE')
    {
      return edited_row;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}



function alertManagers(e)
{
  var clearance_row = checkClearance(e);
  
  if(clearance_row <= 0)
  {
    return;
  }
  
  sendEmailByRow(clearance_row);
}

function sendEmailByRow(row)
{
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1,row,16).getValues();
  var row_values = values[0];
  
  var mail = composeAlertEmail(row_values);
  var manageremail='test@gmail.com';

  //Uncomment this line for testing
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" subject is "+mail.subject+"\n message "+mail.message);
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(manageremail,mail.subject,mail.message);
  

}



function composeAlertEmail(row_values)
{
  var name = row_values[6];
  
  var email = "test@gmail.com";

  var message = "Good day, \n The following employee does not have clearance to enter the building: "+name+
    " email "+email;
  var subject = "Employee Not Cleared: "+name+" "
  
  return({message:message,subject:subject});
}
```

Does this seem possible? I know I am probably far off from a solution, but thanks if anyone can help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

Here is what you are looking for:

```
function triggerOnEdit(e) {
sendEmails(e)
}

function sendEmails(e){
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const subject = "This is the subject of the email";
  const body = "This is the body of the email";
  const to = "director1@gmail.com";
  const cc = "manager1@gmail.com";
  
  if(as.getName() == "Calculations" && col == 16 && as.getRange(row,col).getDisplayValue() == "FALSE") {  

   if (as.getRange(row,10).getValue()=="Building 1"){

      if(as.getRange(row,9).getValue()=="Department 1"){
   
         MailApp.sendEmail({to:to ,subject: subject,body:body,cc:cc});
      }
      else {
         MailApp.sendEmail({to: to,subject: subject,body:body});
      }
   
   }      
  }
}
```

I assume that if **column J** does not match **Building 1** which means there is no recipient, the email won't be sent.

Don't forget to add `triggerOnEdit(e)` to the current project's trigger:

[image: project]